# Disable fullscreen mode in iOS Media Player Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, button, media-player, hide

I want to restrict the media player from entering into the fullscreen mode. Is it possible to customize the controllers of the iPhone media player controller? Can we disable the fullscreen 
button in the media player controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `fullscreen` property and `setFullscreen:animated` methods as noted in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Edit:
I believe I misread your question--apologies.

Not the best solution, but you could override `setFullscreen:` to simply ignore the request:

```
 - (void)setFullscreen:(BOOL)full {
      // Ignore request      
 }
```

As far as customizing the controls, you have the option of setting the `controlStyle`, but all of these have a full screen button, save the "MPMovieControlStyleNone", which give you no controls. You *could* combine the MPMovieControlStyleNone and overlay your own control bar.

I would probably go for the latter myself, as a disabled button I expect to work as a user would probably be frustrating.

Hope that at least partially earns-away that down vote. :-)

Edit: *Adding some more info/code*

So here's just something simple you could do. I build a toolbar using IB

[image: toolbar.tiff]

and a bit of code for placement and some silly color (this one's a little harsh actually):

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"bar" owner:self options:nil];
UIToolbar *toolbar;
if ( nil != array ) {
    toolbar = array[0];
}

CGSize barSize = CGSizeMake(self.window.frame.size.width, 44);
CGSize winSize = self.window.frame.size;

[toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, winSize.height - barSize.height, winSize.width, barSize.height)];
[toolbar setTranslucent:YES];
[toolbar setBackgroundImage:nil forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:138/255 green:187/255 blue:255/227 alpha:0.4]];

[self.window addSubview:toolbar];
```

Just connect up the buttons, maybe do a clear-color overlay to handle the tap-to-bring-up-controls functionality that's already common in the movie players.

Comment: From the docs: "The value of this property may also change as a result of the user interacting with the movie player controls". I don't see how this portion of the docs helps.

Comment: This is not actually  i want, It is already play the video in full screen as i set view width height for MPMoviePlayerController.attributes  set as follows   self.controlStyle =MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;  
 self.scalingMode =MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;                         Then no need of fulscreen button at the controller bar.

Comment: My apologies, @Susitha. It's late and I believe I misread your question. Please see my edits, hopefully that will be of more use to you.

Comment: many thanks @MilesAlden, Is there a way to overlay my own control bar, cant customize the existing control bar

Comment: @Susitha - just made some edits. Hope that points you in the right direction.